# Duplicate symbols Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, google-app-engine

I am trying to use Google Endpoints in an iOS Swift project.

I created the Hello World Endpoints project in Python and I set it up on AppEngine per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/

I am following these instructions to set it up on my project: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_ios#Python_Adding_required_files_to_your_iOS_project 
I am using the Google+ API too.

I am getting stuck on Step 3 of the above. For convenience, I retype it here:

> Your project needs to include the foo.h & foo_Sources.m files
>   generated from ServiceGenerator, which you ran previously, where foo
>   is your API name. Disabling ARC is not required for these files.

In XCode, I go to Add Files and I add the .h and .m files. I also modify my Bridging Header file and I edit my Build Settings Header Search Paths to include the correct paths.

When I try to build, I get this error:

```
Ld /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/WISE normal armv7
    cd /Users/rommelrico/Documents/GitHub/github.sandiego.edu/Mobile/WISEMobile
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk -L/Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/rommelrico/Documents/GitHub/github.sandiego.edu/Mobile/WISEMobile -filelist /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/WISE.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -ObjC -v -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/WISE.swiftmodule -miphoneos-version-min=8.1 -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Security -framework MediaPlayer -framework CoreText -framework GooglePlus -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreMotion -framework CoreLocation -framework Foundation -framework AssetsLibrary -framework GoogleOpenSource -framework AddressBook -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/WISE_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/WISE

Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: arm-apple-darwin14.3.0
Thread model: posix
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch armv7 -dead_strip -iphoneos_version_min 8.1.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk -ObjC -o /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/WISE -L/Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -filelist /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/WISE.LinkFileList -rpath @executable_path/Frameworks -add_ast_path /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/WISE.swiftmodule -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Security -framework MediaPlayer -framework CoreText -framework GooglePlus -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreMotion -framework CoreLocation -framework Foundation -framework AssetsLibrary -framework GoogleOpenSource -framework AddressBook -dependency_info /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/WISE_dependency_info.dat -framework Foundation -lobjc -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.1.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.ios.a -F/Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/rommelrico/Documents/GitHub/github.sandiego.edu/Mobile/WISEMobile
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLHelloworldHelloGreeting in:
    /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GTLHelloworldHelloGreeting.o
    /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GTLHelloworld_Sources.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLHelloworldHelloGreeting in:
    /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GTLHelloworldHelloGreeting.o
    /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GTLHelloworld_Sources.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLServiceHelloworld in:
    /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GTLHelloworld_Sources.o
    /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GTLServiceHelloworld.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLServiceHelloworld in:
    /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GTLHelloworld_Sources.o
    /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GTLServiceHelloworld.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLQueryHelloworld in:
    /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GTLHelloworld_Sources.o
    /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GTLQueryHelloworld.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLQueryHelloworld in:
    /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GTLHelloworld_Sources.o
    /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GTLQueryHelloworld.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLHelloworldHelloGreetingCollection in:
    /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GTLHelloworld_Sources.o
    /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GTLHelloworldHelloGreetingCollection.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLHelloworldHelloGreetingCollection in:
    /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GTLHelloworld_Sources.o
    /Users/rommelrico/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WISE-cscxdkqblzamtvezakprtiqcthrm/Build/Intermediates/WISE.build/Debug-iphoneos/WISE.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GTLHelloworldHelloGreetingCollection.o
ld: 9 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**My Observations**:

It looks like the import statements in the .m files are causing issues. I am following Google's documentation to the letter for their SDK, so I'm wondering if this is a Swift/Objective-C limitation. I did see someone was able to set it up on Github, though: https://github.com/soundTricker/swift-cloud-endpoint-sample

**Here are my questions**:

1. Why does it say "9 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7"? I am counting exactly 8 "duplicate symbol" error messages...
2. Where do I add "-v" to see invocations?
3. What are those .o files? What exactly are the 9 duplicate symbols that I need to fix?
4. I am thinking a way to get around this is to create a framework out of my Google Endpoints API files. That way, I can only include the .h files in my project. Is this a bad idea?

FYI: I am using Google's code exactly cloned from their Github repositories just to rule out any issues with my code. I get the same issues even on a clean project. I am using Xcode v.6.3.1.

-Rommel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out my issue. The Google API ServiceGenerator generates a bunch of files implementation and header files which the Google documentation states to add to your project. Unfortunately, it also generates a _Sources.m file with conflicting import statements. I deleted this file from my iOS Project and the project built successfully.